# The variance of Q in QR decomposition of linear model in rstanarm

Tags: bayesian, stan

I'm trying to understand this article "[Estimating regularized linear models with rstanarm](http://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/articles/lm.html#alternative-approach)", but I'm having trouble with the section "Priors". As background, we are working with the linear model under QR reparameterization:

$$y = X\beta + \alpha + \epsilon = Q\theta + \alpha +\epsilon, $$

where $\theta = R\beta$ and $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma_Y^2)$.

The vignette says:

> To understand this prior, think about the equations that characterize the maximum likelihood solutions before observing the data on $X$ and especially $y$

then

> We can write its $k$th element as $\theta_k=\rho_k \sigma_Y \sqrt{N-1}$ where $ρ_k$ is the correlation between the $k$th column of $Q$ and the outcome, $σ_Y$ is the standard deviation of the outcome, and $\sqrt{N−1}$ is the standard deviation of the $k$th column of $Q$.

No proof is given for any of these statements and I'm having trouble working them out for myself.